# Как получить для всплывающего окна связанный с ним маркер,

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leafletjs

Стоит задача программно вызывать всплывающие сообщения у маркеров на карте не нарушая при этом логики их работы. 
Один из мне известных мне способов  - поставить маркер в фокус:

```
$scope.markers['m1'].focus = true;
```

Однако при клике на маркере мышкой это свойство не изменяется автоматически - что нарушает работу при программном вызове.

Так как события вызываются в следующем порядке:

1. leafletDirectiveMap.popupopen
2. leafletDirectiveMarker.click

и при изменении значения FOCUS в обработчике клика - попап закрывается сразу же, вижу два пути решения этой проблемы:

1 - Получить маркер в обработчике создания окна (не нашёл в среди параметров аргументов обработчика никакого намёка на связанный с попапом маркер)
2 - Изменять значение FOCUS при клике, но избежать при этом вызова связанных с изменением обработчиков.
Но в части реализации этих 2х идей пока мыслей никаких.
Вот простейший код для примера:

```js
var app = angular.module('demoapp',['leaflet-directive']);

app.controller('DemoController', [ '$scope', 'leafletData', function($scope, leafletData) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
        center: {
            lat: 59.91,
            lng: 10.70,
            zoom: 5
        },
        markers: {
            m1: {
                lat: 58.91,
                lng: 10.75,
                message: "<popup></popup>", //directive
                focus: false
            },
   m2: {
                lat: 57.91,
                lng: 10.95,
                message: "<popup></popup>", //directive
                focus: false
            }
   
        },
    });

   $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.popupopen', function(e, args){
      //GET POPUP MARKER!
    }); 

   $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.click', function(e, args){
        //$scope.markers[args.modelName].focus = true;  
    });
}]);
```